# im4java read an image

Tags: java, image, im4java

I tried to read an image in Java with the library im4java:

```
File file = new File("img\\test.jpg");
Info imageInfo = new Info(file.getPath(),true);
```

The problem is that Info() don´t recognize the image. An exception is called:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.im4java.core.InfoException: org.im4java.core.CommandException:      java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "identify": CreateProcess error=2, The sistem can not find the specific file.
at org.im4java.core.Info.getBaseInfo(Info.java:360)
at org.im4java.core.Info.<init>(Info.java:151)
at FeatureExtractor.main(FeatureExtractor.java:51)
```

In the route I tried to put the complete route but it not works. Then I tried to do it with the comand and the operation, and don't work:

```
    // create command
ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();
//cmd.setSearchPath("img");

// create the operation, add images and operators/options
IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
op.addImage("img\\test.jpg");
```

The error is:

```
org.im4java.core.CommandException: org.im4java.core.CommandException: Specification not valid.
at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.run(ImageCommand.java:219)
at FeatureExtractor.main(FeatureExtractor.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the search path for ImageMagick installation and try:

```java
ProcessStarter.setGlobalSearchPath("$PATH:<<ImageMagick/bin>>");
```